# how code for show image from url when tap on image view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an iPhone apps in which i want to insert a event like as when user tap on image view then a image view open which upload image from URL instead of zoom function. how can i do that in my code ? i show my code below:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

    // Tap view for background
    tapView = [[UIViewTap alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    tapView.tapDelegate = self;
    tapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    tapView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self addSubview:tapView];

    // Image view
    photoImageView = [[UIImageViewTap alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    photoImageView.tapDelegate = self;
    photoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    photoImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self addSubview:photoImageView];

    // Spinner
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    spinner.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    [self addSubview:spinner];

    // Setup
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.delegate = self;
    self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

}
return self;}

- (void)setIndex:(NSUInteger)value {
if (value == NSNotFound) {

    // Release image
    photoImageView.image = nil;

} else {

    // Reset for new page at index
    index = value;

    // Display image
    [self displayImage];

}
```

}

// Get and display image

```
- (void)displayImage {
if (index != NSNotFound && photoImageView.image == nil) {

    // Reset
    self.maximumZoomScale = 1;
    self.minimumZoomScale = 1;
    self.zoomScale = 1;
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

    // Get image
    UIImage *img = [self.photoBrowser imageAtIndex:index];
    if (img) {

        // Hide spinner
        [spinner stopAnimating];

        // Set image
        photoImageView.image = img;
        photoImageView.hidden = NO;

        // Setup photo frame
        CGRect photoImageViewFrame;
        photoImageViewFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
        photoImageViewFrame.size = img.size;
        photoImageView.frame = photoImageViewFrame;
        self.contentSize = photoImageViewFrame.size;

        // Set zoom to minimum zoom
        [self setMaxMinZoomScalesForCurrentBounds];

    } else {

        // Hide image view
        photoImageView.hidden = YES;
        [spinner startAnimating];

    }
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

}

// Image failed so just show black!

```
 - (void)displayImageFailure {
[spinner stopAnimating];
```

}

```
- (void)setMaxMinZoomScalesForCurrentBounds {

// Reset
self.maximumZoomScale = 1;
self.minimumZoomScale = 1;
self.zoomScale = 1;

// Bail
if (photoImageView.image == nil) return;

// Sizes
CGSize boundsSize = self.bounds.size;
CGSize imageSize = photoImageView.frame.size;

// Calculate Min
CGFloat xScale = boundsSize.width / imageSize.width;    // the scale needed to perfectly fit the image width-wise
CGFloat yScale = boundsSize.height / imageSize.height;  // the scale needed to perfectly fit the image height-wise
CGFloat minScale = MIN(xScale, yScale);                 // use minimum of these to allow the image to become fully visible

// If image is smaller than the screen then ensure we show it at
// min scale of 1
if (xScale > 1 && yScale > 1) {
    minScale = 1.0;
}

// Calculate Max
CGFloat maxScale = 2.0; // Allow double scale
// on high resolution screens we have double the pixel density, so we will be seeing every pixel if we limit the
// maximum zoom scale to 0.5.
if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    maxScale = maxScale / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
}

// Set
self.maximumZoomScale = maxScale;
self.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
self.zoomScale = minScale;

// Reset position
photoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, photoImageView.frame.size.width, photoImageView.frame.size.height);
[self setNeedsLayout];
```

}

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

// Update tap view frame
tapView.frame = self.bounds;

// Spinner
if (!spinner.hidden) spinner.center = CGPointMake(floorf(self.bounds.size.width/2.0),
                                                  floorf(self.bounds.size.height/2.0));
// Super
[super layoutSubviews];

// Center the image as it becomes smaller than the size of the screen
CGSize boundsSize = self.bounds.size;
CGRect frameToCenter = photoImageView.frame;

// Horizontally
if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
    frameToCenter.origin.x = floorf((boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2.0);
} else {
    frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;
}

// Vertically
if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
    frameToCenter.origin.y = floorf((boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2.0);
} else {
    frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;
}

// Center
if (!CGRectEqualToRect(photoImageView.frame, frameToCenter))
    photoImageView.frame = frameToCenter;
```

}

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
return photoImageView;}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
[photoBrowser cancelControlHiding];
```

}

```
 - (void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view {
[photoBrowser cancelControlHiding];
```

}

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
[photoBrowser hideControlsAfterDelay];
```

}

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(CGPoint)touchPoint {
[photoBrowser performSelector:@selector(toggleControls) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
```

}

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(CGPoint)touchPoint {

// Cancel any single tap handling
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:photoBrowser];

// Zoom
if (self.zoomScale == self.maximumZoomScale) {

    // Zoom out
    [self setZoomScale:self.minimumZoomScale animated:YES];

} else {

    // Zoom in
    [self zoomToRect:CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 1, 1) animated:YES];
}

// Delay controls
[photoBrowser hideControlsAfterDelay];
```

}

// Image View

```
 - (void)imageView:(UIImageView *)imageView singleTapDetected:(UITouch *)touch { [self handleSingleTap:[touch locationInView:imageView]]; }

 - (void)imageView:(UIImageView *)imageView doubleTapDetected:(UITouch *)touch { [self handleDoubleTap:[touch locationInView:imageView]]; }
```

// Background View

```
- (void)view:(UIView *)view singleTapDetected:(UITouch *)touch { [self handleSingleTap:[touch locationInView:view]]; } 

 - (void)view:(UIView *)view doubleTapDetected:(UITouch *)touch {
    [self handleDoubleTap:[touch locationInView:view]]; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this task this way. When you add image to scrollView add a transparent button over imageView and then from the button's action get the URL of that particular image from your array or somewhere else where you have stored and then using HTTPRequest upload the image.

Comment: thanks for ur answer can u tell me how make transparent button?

Comment: UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

Comment: image view not adding uibutton.

Comment: you don't need add button to imageView just add button to scrollview at the same frame where image is.

Comment: i have no of image in image vie and add image view to scroll view.so i do that

Comment: I am from bikaner. Right now I am in hyderabad. I live near junagarh fort near minerva cinema. Are you from bikaner?

Comment: @ram where are you from and where you work? If you are from bikaner and you work in bikaner I assume you are working in ISOL or sunarc